# No Internet Connection after plugging of second wifi interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, network-interface, dnsmasq

I've set up ubuntu server (16.04TLS) as Access Point with hostapd and dnsmasq.
For internet connection I use my built-in wifi network card (RTLINK) and for Access Point - wifi-usb adapter. 
Without Wifi-Usb being plugged in there is stable internet connection (I can surf internet with curl). After plugging USb-Stick (Edimax EW-7811Un) in, I can connect my devices to it (it broadcasts access point), but then there is no more any internet connection.

What can be a problem?

Gateway is 192.168.2.1

rc.local

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 ! -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
    auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlx74da382e3878
iface wlx74da382e3878 inet static
hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
address 192.168.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlo1
allow-hotplug wlo1
iface wlo1 inet dhcp 
...wpa-settings
```

$ifconfig (wlo1 used for connection to ADSL-Router for Internet connection)

```
 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:15885 (15.8 KB)  TX bytes:15885 (15.8 KB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:85:56:47:69:37
          inet addr:192.168.2.103  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::be85:56ff:fe47:6937/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6935 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2412406 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:78228 (78.2 KB)

wlx74da382e3878 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:2e:38:78
          inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76da:38ff:fe2e:3878/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:792 (792.0 B)
```

iwconfig ( wlx74da382e3878 (usb-wifi-adapter) serves as Access Point)

```
> wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"TP-LINK_D"
>           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: A0:F3:C1:D7:33:38
>           Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
>           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>           Encryption key:off
>           Power Management:off
>           Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm
>           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:11   Missed beacon:0
> 
> wlx74da382e3878  IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm
>           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>           Power Management:on
```

hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlx74da382e3878
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
ssid=TEST-WLAN
hw_mode=g
channel=1
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
rts_threshold=2347
fragm_threshold=2346
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=3
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
eapol_key_index_workaround=0
eap_server=0
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wmm_enabled=1
```

$route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlo1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlo1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlx74da382e3878
```

Comment: don't use the same iprange with same netmask on 2 dirrerent interfaces.

Comment: sorry, where is it to configure? and how would be it properly to set up?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Ipor Sircer with his comment was right, I'd used somehow the same ip-range in my settings (for AP-connection and for Managed-connection). 
As my Router has 192.168.2.1 gateway-ip, I'd set up the same range for my Hostapd-wifi-adapter. 
The problem was resolved after setting up the address for hostapd on 10.0.0.1